# c# Remove Duplicates in my case statement. Making Case statement Dynamic

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there a way I can avoid duplicates in my case statement? I want my code to be dynamic as possible.

```
 public void LoadTemplate()
        {
            switch (this.GetTemplate)
            {
                case 0://Default
                    this.configForm.txtDSN1.Text = Configuration.Default.ServerParameters.DSN.ToString();
                    this.configForm.comboServer.Text = Configuration.Default.ServerParameters.Server.ToString();
                    this.configForm.comboDatabase.Text = Configuration.Default.ServerParameters.Database.ToString();
                    break;
                case 1://Retail
                    this.configForm.txtDSN1.Text = Configuration.Retail.ServerParameters.DSN.ToString();
                    this.configForm.comboServer.Text = Configuration.Retail.ServerParameters.Server.ToString();
                    this.configForm.comboDatabase.Text = Configuration.Retail.ServerParameters.Database.ToString();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Here's my constants inside Configuration Class.

```
//Default Template
        public partial class Default
        { 
            public partial class ServerParameters
            {
                public const string DSN = "Default";
                public const string Server = "";
                public const string Database = "";
            }
        }
        //Retail Template
        public partial class Retail
        {
            public partial class ServerParameters
            {
                public const string DSN = "Retail1";
                public const string Server = "";
                public const string Database = "";
            }
        }
```

I'm new at c# I could use a good practice. Thanks

Comment: why do you call ToString at the end?

Answer (score 3):

You are essentially trying to define configuration behavior based on selecting a configuration strategy. Since you already have two classes that have knowledge of the different configuration strategies, you may want to consider refactoring your classes to follow the [Strategy Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern).

- Create an interface that has a method that accepts your form.
- Have both of your classes Default and Retail implement that interface. Each implementation of that method performs the necessary form configuration. You do not even need the constants anymore.
- Then, it is a matter resolving the strategy. This can be done using a case statement, a data mapping, or even dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the follwing using reflection:

```
    string className= this.GetTemplate==0?"Default":"Retail";

    Type objType = Type.GetType("Configuration."+className);
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
    objType.GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);

    this.configForm.txtDSN1.Text = objType.GetProperty("ServerParameters.DSN").GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
    this.configForm.comboServer.Text = objType.GetProperty("ServerParameters.Server").GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
    this.configForm.comboDatabase.Text = objType.GetProperty("ServerParameters.Database").GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
```

This is choosing what class name you need to get properties from, then simply use [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/mt656691.aspx) to get properties from it. It may not be the best option, but you can use it, not to modify your architecture if it has a powerful impact on your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code flexible by defining a generic provider for the `ServerParameters` type. To do that, create a provider interface like this:

```
public interface IProvider<TId, TEntity>
{
     TEntity Provide(TId id);
}
```

Then, create an implementation for this interface that would generate an instance of `ServerParameters` with the values that you want based on the template code or whatever you're using to identify a template.

To do that you have to extract the `ServerParameters` class and create only a single definition of it. Also, change your property definitions in `ServerParameters` to be variables and not constants.

Then, your provider implementation would be like this:

```
public class ServerParametersProvider : IProvider<int, ServerParameters>
{
     public ServerParameters Provide(int templateCode)
     {
          //For each templateCode return a ServerParameters instance with the required values.
          return null;
     }
}
```

Then, in the class that contains the `LoadTemplate` method, inject an instance of the provider through the interface reference. Finally, your `LoadTemplate` method would look like this:

```
public void LoadTemplate()
{
     var parameters = m_Provider.Provide(GetTemplate);

     configForm.txtDSN1.Text = parameters.DSN;
     configForm.comboServer.Text = parameters.Server;
     configForm.comboDatabase.Text = parameters.Database;
}
```

This way, your UI or whatever context your `LoadTemplate` is in is not does not change when you have another template code that you need to provide values for, you just change the provider to return a different instance of `ServerParameters` with different values.

You can even make your code more flexible by making your provider depend on specific providers for specific template codes and delegate to those providers based on the code that it receives as parameter.